# Como rastrear o evento de scroll de um elemento (não a window) usando uma diretiva no Angular (v2+)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-7

Olá, estou criando uma tela com essa estrutura:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="appbar">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="main" #main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

- O `wrapper` tem o tamanho total da tela, sendo que ele é flex.
- O `appbar` persiste os menus referentes a solução.
- O `main` é onde as rotas são renderizadas. somente ele tem scroll

Meu problema é o seguinte. Quando eu tento rastrear a `window` a partir de um HostListener, eu não consigo detectar que o main teve algum tipo de scroll..

meu componente está assim até o momento:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.scss']
})
export class OverviewComponent {
  @ViewChild('main') mainRef: HTMLElement;
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScroll(e:Event) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

O que preciso fazer para conseguir rastrear o scroll que ocorre dentro do main?